# How to pass parent class instance in place of child class instances in polymorphic functions?

Tags: java, generics

I have two classes `Event1` and `Event2`. At runtime, I want to create instance of `Event1` or `Event2` using java reflection and pass it as a parameter to another function. That function is a polymorphic function, which depending upon the input parameter type, invokes the corresponding functionality.

Since I don't know what kind of child event instance I may need to create at runtime, I extend both child classes from 'Event' class and create a parent class instance. My question is, can I pass instance of 'Event' class as a parameter, which will be resolved at runtime to one of the child classes for polymorphic functions.

Here is my code.

```
public void myFunc(){

    String qualifiedName = new String("events.Event1"); // Event1 info is actually obtained at runtime. 

    Class cls = Class.forName(qualifiedName);
    Event baseEvent = (Event) cls.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(); 
    // I want to create an instance like, Event ev1 = new Event1(); and pass it as a parameter.

    observer.update(baseEvent);  // I get compile time error because no update method takes `Event` class instance as parameter.
}
```

Observer class that contains polymorphic functions.

```
public void update(Event1);
public void update(Event2);
```

Can Java generics help here? Thanks.

Comment: You need to use reflection to find the right method to call for the type of Event you have.

Comment: I think you may use [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to not rely on reflection unless you have specific rules or needs to use reflection only.

Comment: I guess, factory method will also give me a parent class, to be resolved at run time, like Shape shape = factory.getShape("Car"); Though it would return a Car instance at runtime, but at compile time, I will have parent class instance. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Using reflection to invoke methods seems workable..I am going to try that.

Comment: You will have the same result: an object reference to the sub class but the type of the super class. The differences will be implementation, maintenance and code readability. It's up to you which one to use, but I would recommend factory pattern since it is easier to understand and maintain than using reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Method method = observer.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("update", baseEvent.getClass());
    method.invoke(observer, baseEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

First some terminology: if you have a method with same name but different paramters in the same class / interface, like this:

```
public void update(Event1 e);
public void update(Event2 e);
```

It is called *overloaded*, not *polymorphic*. (Good to know if you want to google something on this topic).

Second, answer to your question: No. Java polymorphism is't meant for this. If you call previous update method like this:

```
Event e = //get Event from anywhere
update(e);
```

Compiler will not be able to decide what overloaded version of `update()` to call, because Java polymorhism doesn't work on overloaded methods.

You could do try to cast it to see what type it acctually is:

```
try {
    update((Event1) e);
} catch(ClassCastException ex) {
    //do nothing
}
try {
    update((Event2) e);
} catch(ClassCastException ex) {
    //do nothing
}
```

Now if `e` was in fact `Event1` or `Event2`, proper method will be called. But this requires to know all subbclasses of `Event` at compile time (unless you want to get a bit dirty and use reflexion).

Comment: To do a try catch is not really recommended, instead of this and to avoid reflection you could use a Map<Class,Runnable> so you can do something like runnable= map.get(event.getClass()).run(), and any Runnable executes the proper code.

Answer (score 0):

By the way.. I prefer this approach (avoid reflection):

```
Map<Class<? extends Event>,Runnable> actionMapper= new HashMap<Class<? extends Event>, Runnable>();
    actionMapper.put(Event1.class, new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Execution for event 1");
        }
    });

    actionMapper.put(Event2.class, new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Execution for event 2");
        }
    });


    Event event= new Event1();
    Runnable action = actionMapper.get(event.getClass());
    action.run();
```